# Postgres ODBC Driver generates +100 connection attempt using different ports when used in Alteryx. Why?

Tags: postgresql, odbc, alteryx

I'm using psqlodbc_15_00_0000 and Alteryx 23.1. When using the ODBC driver no logs are created apart of standards. When used in Alteryx, while port **54338 **is configured in the setup screen of the ODBC, logs will show +100 connection attempts using multiple ports. This happens on multiple machines.

[image: Setup screen ODBC]

Log sample:

```
2024-01-17 14:31:05.378 CET [1960709] : [1-1] db=[unknown],user=[unknown],app=[unknown],client= LOG:  connection received: host= port=57126
2024-01-17 14:31:05.398 CET [1960709] : [2-1] db=,user=,app=[unknown],client= LOG:  connection authenticated: identity="CN=,OU=,DC=,DC=,DC=fr" method=ldap (9)
2024-01-17 14:31:05.398 CET [1960709] : [3-1] db=,user=,app=[unknown],client= LOG:  connection authorized: user= database=29rp1rrb
2024-01-17 14:31:05.422 CET [1960709] : [4-1] db=,user=,app=[unknown],client= LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.044 user=_ database= host= port=57126
2024-01-17 14:31:14.944 CET [1960797] : [1-1] db=[unknown],user=[unknown],app=[unknown],client= LOG:  connection received: host= port=**57198**
2024-01-17 14:31:14.958 CET [1960797] : [2-1] db=,user=,app=[unknown],client= LOG:  connection authenticated: identity="CN=,OU=,DC=,DC=,DC=fr" method=ldap (9)
2024-01-17 14:31:14.958 CET [1960797] : [3-1] db=,user=,app=[unknown],client= LOG:  connection authorized: user= database=2
2024-01-17 14:31:14.980 CET [1960797] : [4-1] db=,user=,app=[unknown],client= LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.036 user=_ database= host= port=57198
```

Logs also shows multiple errors:

```
2024-01-17 14:06:49.598 CET [1950358] : [4-1] db=,user=zsiq_alteryx,app=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver 1.5.2.1002,client=10.208.11.222 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "
(" at character 12
2024-01-17 14:06:49.598 CET [1950358] : [5-1] db=,user=zsiq_alteryx,app=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver 1.5.2.1002,client=10.208.11.222 STATEMENT:  select USER(), APPLIC
ATION_ID() from system.iota
2024-01-17 14:06:49.599 CET [1950358] : [6-1] db=,user=zsiq_alteryx,app=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver 1.5.2.1002,client=10.208.11.222 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "
(" at character 12
2024-01-17 14:06:49.599 CET [1950358] : [7-1] db=,user=zsiq_alteryx,app=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver 1.5.2.1002,client=10.208.11.222 STATEMENT:  select USER(), APPLIC
ATION_ID() from system.iota
2024-01-17 14:06:49.605 CET [1950358] : [8-1] db=,user=zsiq_alteryx,app=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver 1.5.2.1002,client=10.208.11.222 ERROR:  relation "sysibm.sysdummy
1" does not exist at character 31
2024-01-17 14:06:49.605 CET [1950358] : [9-1] db=,user=zsiq_alteryx,app=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver 1.5.2.1002,client=10.208.11.222 STATEMENT:  select USER as USER_N
AME from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
2024-01-17 14:06:49.605 CET [1950358] : [10-1] db=,user=zsiq_alteryx,app=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver 1.5.2.1002,client=10.208.11.222 ERROR:  relation "sysibm.sysdumm
y1" does not exist at character 31
2024-01-17 14:06:49.605 CET [1950358] : [11-1] db=,user=zsiq_alteryx,app=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver 1.5.2.1002,client=10.208.11.222 STATEMENT:  select USER as USER_
NAME from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
2024-01-17 14:06:49.611 CET [1950358] : [12-1] db=,user=zsiq_alteryx,app=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver 1.5.2.1002,client=10.208.11.222 ERROR:  relation "rdb$relations"
 does not exist at character 15
2024-01-17 14:06:49.611 CET [1950358] : [13-1] db=,user=zsiq_alteryx,app=PostgreSQL ODBC Driver 1.5.2.1002,client=10.208.11.222 STATEMENT:  select * from rdb$re
lations
```

Any ideas on on how to solve this issue?

I tried using the same ODBC driver on Excel, without any issues. We tried using different drivers without any changes (Simba driver as presented in Alteryx Help).

Answer (score 1):

The ports you see in the log are (ephemeral) *client* ports. It looks like your client software is opening several database connections, probably for a connection pool, which is a good thing.